# Understanding what range is in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm completely new and confused. I know what `for i in range` is but what does it mean when we multiply `i` and `j`? 
For example:

```
for i in range(10):

    drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * i, y + 0),
     Point(x + 5 + 20 * i, y + 90)
```

what does `20 * i` mean? Are we doing `x + 10` twenty times in succession?

Aren't we already telling it to do it ten times above?

Sorry if there's a similar question here, if so I couldn't find it.

Comment: It does exactly what you told it to: `20 * i` with `i` ranging from `0` to `9`.

Comment: `i` is a number. `20 * i` is just 20 times the value of `i` for that iteration

Comment: `i` is not the range; `i` is a single `int` *from* the range; the `for` loop works by assigning values from the range to `i` in sequence.

Comment: "but what does it mean when we multiply i and j" -- there is no `j` in your code. Are you asking what multiplication means? There is no secret meaning here -- it is just ordinary multiplication of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple calculation. The loop has 10 iterations and sets i to 0, ..., 9. Hence:

First iteration:
i == 0
First Point's x coord: x + 10 + 20*0 = x + 10

Second iteration:
i == 1
First Point's x coord: x + 10 + 20*1 = x + 30

And so on.

(Note that your code seems to have syntax errors.)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR The `for` loop takes care of setting `i` repeatedly to a different value from the range each time through the loop.

---

A `range` value is an iterable; if you pass it to the `iter` function, you get back a value you can pass to `next` to get each value. Once the sequence is exhausted, you'll get a `StopIteration` exception.

```
>>> r = iter(range(3))
>>> next(r)
0
>>> next(r)
1
>>> next(r)
2
>>> next(r)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Suppose you wanted to make a set of related calls

```
drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * 0, y + 0), Point(x + 5 + 20 * 0, y + 90)
drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * 1, y + 0), Point(x + 5 + 20 * 1, y + 90)
drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * 2, y + 0), Point(x + 5 + 20 * 2, y + 90)
```

but didn't want to repeat yourself so much. Lets's start with something even *longer* (which seems like the wrong direction to go, but it will make sense in a moment):

```
r = iter(range(3))
i = next(r)  # i == 0
drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * i, y + 0), Point(x + 5 + 20 * i, y + 90)
i = next(r)  # i == 1
drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * i, y + 0), Point(x + 5 + 20 * i, y + 90)
i = next(r)  # i == 2
drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * i, y + 0), Point(x + 5 + 20 * i, y + 90)
```

More code, but notice that the call to `drawSomething` looks identical each time; the only difference is that the *value* of `i` has changed. We'd like to avoid having to explicitly repeat the calls to `next` and `drawSomething`, so we'll use a loop. Let's start with a `while` loop.

```
r = iter(range(3))
while True:
    try:
        i = next(r)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * i, y + 0), Point(x + 5 + 20 * i, y + 90)
```

Still long, but notice that nothing in the loop now depends on any particular value of `r`: if we said `r = iter(range(1000))`, the loop would stay the same size, but the equivalent listing of function calls would be *far* larger.

But we can do better. Here, there was a lot of boilerplate code we had to write before we could get to what we *really* wanted (the call to `drawSomething`):

1. call `iter` on `r` to get an iterator
2. explicitly call `next` to get each value of `i`
3. check if `next` raised an exception to signal an exit to the loop

The `for` loop handles all three for us:

```
r = range(3)

# Calls iter(r)
# Calls i = next(r), catching the StopIteration exception when it gets raised
# Exits the loop when the exception is caught
for i in r:
    drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * i, y + 0), Point(x + 5 + 20 * i, y + 90)
```

Further, since we only use the name `r` once, we can drop it and use `range` directly in the loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    drawSomething(win, Point(x + 10 + 20 * i, y + 0), Point(x + 5 + 20 * i, y + 90)
```